# mod rewrite adjust REQUEST_URI proxy

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy, mod-proxy

I setup one virtual host which proxies back to a number of different local URLs based on the appended directory (resource in the URI). I can pull it off using ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse, but the issue comes (local) application presents a splash page. This is on Apache2.2.

With mod_proxy setup I have this:

```
ProxyPass /VirtualConnect/ https://backend-app1.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse /VirtualConenct/ https://backend-app1.example.com/
```

When accessing the app application through the reverse Proxy URL for VirtualConnect, the back-end application presents a splash page with a series of links, and when you hover over the links it shows the Proxy server hostname and the file name linked to it, but the "/VirtualConnect/" portion of the URL is removed resulting in the link breaking when you click on it. I'm assuming this is a result of not using relative URLs on that splash page. Can I fix/address this with mod rewrite. I do not have access to the back end application. I tried with the following with respect to mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://backend-app1.example.com/$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://backend-app1.example.com/VirtualConnect/
```

I've also tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^VirtualConnect/
RewriteRule /VirtualConnect/ https://backend-app1.example.com/%1/$1 [P]
```

Based on my understanding the condition is met when the URL initially starts with VirtualConnect, and if true, it says rewrite the the URL with the /VirtualConnect/ appended to https://backend-app1.example.com/ (i.e. by way of %1) and then the $1 would be anything clicked on at that point.

Any help would be great, or if you can just point me to some documentation that I may not have read already.

Cheers,

**UPDATE**
I hvae this rule which works in the sense of proxying. In reality I could have accomplished this by just using mod_proxy.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/VirtualConnect/?
RewriteRule ^/VirtualConnect/?(.*) https://backend-app1.example.com%1/$1/?$ [P,L]
```

Now when I visit https://backend-app1.example.com/VirtualConnect (with out without a ending slash, I get the desired results. It takes me to a page with links. When you hove over one of the links in the splash page it show the following in the status at the bottom of the browser: https://backend-app1.example.com/backup/. Which will break, because the current rewrite rule is dependent on the request_uri containing /VirtualConnect/. If I deliberately type https://backend-app1.example.com/VirtualConnect/backup/ I get to the desired page, but what I need is a rewrite rule that makes the adjustments from  https://backend-app1.example.com/backup/ to https://backend-app1.example.com/VirtualConnect/backup/ when I click on a link that looks like this https://backend-app1.example.com/backup/. I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backup/?
RewriteRule ^/backup/? https://%{SERVER_NAME}/VirtualConnect/backup/?$
```

I was hoping that by putting the rewrite rule directly above first, that it would rewrite the URL to the point where the next rule I spoke of earlier would take affect. But it doesn't work since the actual Rule doesn't modify what is in the address bar. I think.

I just want to know if this is possible. I think in Apache 2.4 the mod_proxy_html module accounts for this situation, but I could have read that wrong.

Thanks again